# iPhone SDK: play a sound with coreAudio

Tags: iphone, audio, core-audio

So far i've been using AudioServices to play sounds in my drum app which caused horrible lag etc.
I've been told that if i use coreAudio there will be no lag abd the performance will be better.The person also told me that AudioServices is only used to play short alert sound.

Any idea where i could start with CoreAudio?

If you have any code, it's helpful too :) but tutorials would be better :D.

Thanks in advance!

-DD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really recommend Apple's documentation and the sample apps they provide:

- [Core Audio Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [Audio Unit Hosting Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)

**Example Apps**

- [Audio Mixer (MixerHost)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MixerHost/Introduction/Intro.html)
- [oalTouch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/oalTouch/Introduction/Intro.html)
- [SpeakHere](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html)
- [iPhoneMultichannelMixerTest](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneMixerEQGraphTest/Introduction/Intro.html)
- [iPhoneMixerEQGraphTest](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneMixerEQGraphTest/Introduction/Intro.html)
- [MusicCube](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MusicCube/Introduction/Intro.html)