# Play MP3/WAV files without using libraries?

Tags: c++, macos, audio

I am using an application called Eclipse (Oxygen Release (4.7.0)), and I am using it on MacOS Sierra. A few days ago, I downloaded [source code](https://github.com/MitchellSternke/Mario) from a replica Mario game that was made with C++ and OpenGL.

I was gonna use that source code to reference and play .mp3/.wav files in my game/program, until I realized that I can't do that because the source code for the Mario replica uses SDL2 and SDL2_Mixer to play all the audio that is used in the replica Mario game.

It is too much of a pain in the butt to import SDL2 and SDL2_Mixer into my C++ game/program, especially since it is harder to do on a Mac. I've tried doing it before, and failed. :(

I noticed that in the Mario replica source code, there were .wav files in the source code, which means that in the code, those .wav files were referenced and used to play the audio.

Is there any way to reference and play audio files in my game/program? I know it will be hard to do, because I am using a Mac, so I cannot use `#include windows(.h);` and other stuff like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd take a look at Apple's Core Audio Framework. See SO question here:

[iPhone SDK: play a sound with coreAudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928636/iphone-sdk-play-a-sound-with-coreaudio)

Comment: Lots of those links have been taken down :( @Pat Mustard

Comment: Plus, those links are for IOS. My game isn't gonna be for IOS. It's gonna be for Macintosh and Windows. Thanks for the help though. :)

Comment: core audio is usable on ios and osx, however, if you want something portable you could use open al (https://openal.org/) or The sound object library (http://sndobj.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks @Pat Mustard! I've just got 1 more question. How would I be able to connect the library to my project, so I can `#Include` it? Thanks for all your help by the way!

Comment: You'll need to download the sources and build whichever one you choose from scratch. After that you would include the headers and link against the library.